# ADF Table Editable Field Issue

Tags: oracle-adf

I am updating an application written in ADF 11.1.1.3. In almost all of my screens, i have ADF Tables with editable fields  and every table has a row selector enabled.

I have a problem where if a user clicks in an editable field, of a  table row that isnt yet selected, the field row selector appears to fire off and then the browser loses the focus on the field that the user intended to select.

[image]

Per my example screen above, the 2nd table row is currently selected. However, if i click inside any editable field in row 3 (like End Date), browser sets the focus on the field. But then the Table Row Selection listener invokes immediately after, and then takes the focus off the field i originally clicked. This happens on any editable field type.

The most annoying thing is when i update a checkbox of a table row (not selected), the value is immediately overwritten back with its original value.

Currently, the only way to get around this problem, is the user first selects the table row, then updates the field data.

Any experience with this issue? I'm thinking about a client listener or value change listener but wanted to see what your thoughts are.

Thanks!

**Update 01:**
I set "immediate" property to "true" for the table, still get the same results. I applied immediate=true to the parent Panel Boxes, same results.

**Update 02:**
The table's Iterator' and Binding's ChangeEventPolicy was set to default (none). But i set it to none anyways. Same results..

**Update 03:**
Removed validators, same result.

Comment: Why do you use row selection?

Comment: There are Master-Detail Relationships setup based on the selected table record. Also the original developer wrote in functionality so users can select table rows, delete them and select next/prev record (i dont know why the next/prev record buttons were added).

Comment: I did find one page where the selection listener and editable fields work properly. At first glance they are almost exactly the same. Difference is the field validators. Another difference is the fact the selection listeners on the functioning page run MUCH quicker. I'm thinking theres extra cycles of validation running that we dont need.

Answer (score 0):

Does your selection listener still retains "#{bindings.xxx.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"? this is used to set the currently selected row as current row, if you have removed this then it means that even when you select the row by clicking on a field, the model still has previous row selected in its iterator.